# replace an unknown number of repeated whitespace with a specific pattern

Tags: r

Take some messy data like this.

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c("Greendale Village Wards 1 & 2                                     405     1,219               20                 5                 1", 
                            "Hales Corners Village Wards 4 - 6                                   400     1,002                7                 6                 2", 
                            "Kenosha City Ward 49                                                    0           0              0                 0                 0"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  x1                                                                                                                                      
  <chr>                                                                                                                                   
1 Greendale Village Wards 1 & 2                                     405     1,219               20                 5                 1    
2 Hales Corners Village Wards 4 - 6                                   400     1,002                7                 6                 2  
3 Kenosha City Ward 49                                                    0           0              0                 0                 0
```

I want to separate this data into columns. I know the columns are separated by >=2 empty spaces, but the specific number of spaces varies.

I'd like to replace all instances of 2-or-more whitespaces with a single occurance of a specific pattern, which I can then use as a delimiter.

Here is a clunky way to do this, where I replace any appearance of    with `!!`, then I replace any instance `!!!` with `!!` until no more remain. Besides being long and clunky, this method requires me to manually decide how many times to run `str_replace_all()`.

What is a cleaner and more reliable way to do this?

```
df |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "  ", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!")) |>
  mutate(x1 = str_replace_all(x1, "!!!", "!!"))
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  x1                                                        
  <chr>                                                     
1 Greendale Village Wards 1 & 2!! 405!! 1,219!! 20!! 5!! 1  
2 Hales Corners Village Wards 4 - 6!! 400!! 1,002!!7!! 6!! 2
3 Kenosha City Ward 49!!0!! 0!!0!! 0!! 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```r
gsub("  +","!! ",df$x1)
```

do what you want? Or the tidyverse-ish

```
mutate(across(x1 , ~str_replace_all(., "  +", "!! ")))
```

The target regex is *two* spaces followed by "+", i.e. "one space followed by one or more spaces"

Answer (score 4):

You can `gsub` and pipe in `read.delim`.

```
> gsub('\\s{2,}', '\t', df$x1) |> read.delim(text=_, header=FALSE)
                                 V1  V2    V3 V4 V5 V6
1     Greendale Village Wards 1 & 2 405 1,219 20  5  1
2 Hales Corners Village Wards 4 - 6 400 1,002  7  6  2
3              Kenosha City Ward 49   0     0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert to exclamation points as a delimiter. You can straight up split the single column into the expected 6 columns

```r
tidyr::separate(df, x1, into = paste0('x', 1:6), sep = ' {2,}')
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   x1                                x2    x3    x4    x5    x6   
#>   <chr>                             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Greendale Village Wards 1 & 2     405   1,219 20    5     1    
#> 2 Hales Corners Village Wards 4 - 6 400   1,002 7     6     2    
#> 3 Kenosha City Ward 49              0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: This is good, but note that `separate()` seems to be deprecated now (!!!) in favour of `separate_wider_regex()` [in this case] ... (tidyr v 1.3.0)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker I didn't know that. I think it has been superseded rather than deprecated though. The newer versions seem to offer a bit more control in the event of an unequal number of pieces being separated out, and use `stringr` for their regex. I'm not convinced this makes up for the extra key strokes in the name for straightforward uses!

Comment: You're right, "superseded".